# Microsoft Bot Framework How to Set Facebook Message Tag

Tags: facebook, tags, botframework, message, proactive

My use case is to be able to send a message outside Facebook's 24 + 1 policy by using message tags as described on [Facebook Dev Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/message-tags).  It states I need to set the **messaging_type and a valid tag**.  I have set the messaging_type but just can't get the tag to work.

At present I get this error from Facebook:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tag is required for MESSAGE_TAG messaging type.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 2018199,
    "fbtrace_id": "GvmKwSrcqVb"
  }
}
```

To me this indicates I have successfully set the messaging_type but not the tag. I have tried adding the tag from other suggestions [GitHub #2924](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2924) in the activity.Properties as below but it didn't work so I've also tried it in the ChannelData which also doesn't work.

```
activity.Properties = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
activity.Properties.Add("tag", "CONFIRMED_EVENT_REMINDER");

activity.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    messaging_type = "MESSAGE_TAG",
    tag = "CONFIRMED_EVENT_REMINDER"
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this seems so close to working but at the same time is really limiting my bot's capabilities.

I've cross posted this on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4154).

Thanks

**Edit - Code Example Added Below**

This is my code, it works fine in all ordinary cases but I can't send a message outside of the Facebook 24 + 1 rule by using message tags.  Some other info is I've migrated my bot on the bot framework portal and it's live on Facebook Messenger where I have pages_messaging approved but haven't applied for pages_messaging_subscriptions.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/outboundtest")]
public class SendBotMessageTestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SendSimpleMessage")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendSimpleMessage([FromBody] BotToCustomerMessageTestDTO dto)
    {
        try
        {
            var conversationRef = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConversationReference>(dto.BotConversationJson);

            // We need to ensure the URL is trusted as we lose this from the in-memory cache of trusted URLs if/when the app pool recycles: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1645
            MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(conversationRef.ServiceUrl);

            var activity = conversationRef.GetPostToBotMessage();

            var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(conversationRef.User.Id, conversationRef.User.Name);
            var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(conversationRef.Bot.Id, conversationRef.Bot.Name);

            activity.ChannelId = conversationRef.ChannelId;
            activity.From = botAccount;
            activity.Recipient = userAccount;
            activity.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationRef.Conversation.Id);
            activity.Locale = "en-Gb";

            var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(conversationRef.ServiceUrl), this.GetCredentials());

            if (activity.ChannelId == "facebook")
            {
                // Add TAG indicate we can send this message outside the allowed window as suggested here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2924
                activity.Properties = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
                activity.Properties.Add("tag", "CONFIRMED_EVENT_REMINDER");

                // Set messaging_type as suggested here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4154 and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/
                activity.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new
                {
                    notification_type = "REGULAR",
                    messaging_type = "MESSAGE_TAG"
                });
            }

            // Send the message:
            activity.Text = dto.Message;
            await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)activity).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            resp.Content = new StringContent($"Message sent", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, @"text/plain");
            return resp;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }

    private MicrosoftAppCredentials GetCredentials()
    {
        return new MicrosoftAppCredentials("ABC", "XYZ");
    }
}

public class BotToCustomerMessageTestDTO
{
    public string BotConversationJson; // Stored from previous reply using activity.ToConversationReference()
    public string Message;      // This is the message to send.
}
```

Comment: I think you can have a look on your messages on Facebook's side to check if the flag is there or not, using Facebook Graph Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Can you please provide the complete code that you are sending and constructive the activity which is causing the error?

Comment: Hi @JasonSowers, please see my code added to the question and my responses to Ma3yTa below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ma3yTa for helping with this.  I don't really know why but your code didn't work for me, maybe because I don't have the page messaging subscription permission from Facebook.

However, if this helps others, this code does work for me (essentially the fix was to put the tag & messaging_type in both the ChannelData and the Properties).

So in C#

```
        if (activity.ChannelId == "facebook")
        {
            // Add TAG indicate we can send this message outside the allowed window:
            activity.Properties.Add("tag", "BUSINESS_PRODUCTIVITY");
            activity.Properties.Add("messaging_type", "MESSAGE_TAG");

            activity.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                messaging_type = "MESSAGE_TAG",
                notification_type = "REGULAR",
                tag = "BUSINESS_PRODUCTIVITY"
            });
        }
```

I have also found that I use replies all over the place which don't preserve the ChannelData or the Properties from the original activity so I created a helper function like this:

```
    public static Activity CreateReply(Activity activity, string message)
    {
        var reply = activity.CreateReply();
        reply.ChannelData = activity.ChannelData;
        reply.Properties = activity.Properties;
        reply.Text = message;

        if (reply.ChannelId == "facebook" && reply.ChannelData == null)
        {
            // If we don't set this you the user doesn't see a notification on their phone:
            reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new { notification_type = "REGULAR" });
        }

        return reply;
    }
```

I can now happily send simple text messages or complex Hero Cards as part of dialog stack using this mechanism.  Finally, I can reliably send out Facebook messages :-)

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me.

```
var starter = new ConversationStarter(conversationReference);
starter.Resume(msg)

public class ConversationStarter
{
    ConversationReference conversationReference;

    public ConversationStarter(ConversationReference cr)
        => conversationReference = cr;

    public async Task Resume(string text)
    {
        IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
        message.Text = text;
        message.Locale = "en-Us";
        await Resume(message);
    }

    public async Task Resume(IMessageActivity message)
    {
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(conversationReference.ServiceUrl));

        //unathorized workaround
        //https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2575
        //https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2155#issuecomment-276964664
        MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(conversationReference.ServiceUrl); 

        message.ChannelId = conversationReference.ChannelId ??
            (await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(conversationReference.Bot, conversationReference.User)).Id;
        message.From = conversationReference.Bot;
        message.Recipient = conversationReference.User;
        message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationReference.Conversation.Id);
        var activity = (Activity)message;
        activity.Properties = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
        activity.Properties.Add("tag", "APPLICATION_UPDATE");
        await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(activity);
    }

    public async Task ResumeAsDialog<T>(IDialog<T> dialog)
    {
        var message = conversationReference.GetPostToBotMessage();
        var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

        using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
        {
            var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
            await botData.LoadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

            //This is our dialog stack
            var task = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();

            //interrupt the stack. This means that we're stopping whatever conversation that is currently happening with the user
            //Then adding this stack to run and once it's finished, we will be back to the original conversation
            task.Call(dialog.Void<T, IMessageActivity>(), null);

            await task.PollAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            //flush dialog stack
            await botData.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the same problem running your code.  .NET Exception "Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest" and on the bot framework portal I get this error:

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Cannot send 'RESPONSE' messaging_type messages outside messaging window",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 2018208,
    "fbtrace_id": "GzdBC3tVbrn"
  }
}

Comment: If I set the messaging_type using activity.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new
                {
                    messaging_type = "MESSAGE_TAG"
                }); then I get a different error which just looks like the tag is missing.
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Tag is required for MESSAGE_TAG messaging type.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018199,"fbtrace_id":"EADNyI\/XPqw"}}